# Can't receive emails send from php

Tags: email, php

I have set up several email accounts on my vps hosting but I can't receive any emails that are send via php from another hosting. Everything works fine when I send emails from gmail for example, I receive them without a trouble. Does anyone know any reason why emails sent from php can't be received?

Comment: are you sure they are being sent?

Comment: Yes I'm sure they are sent... I can receive them on my gmail account.

Comment: I mean log of mail transfer agent when sending to vps hosting accounts from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), it's a good mailing class which automatically sets well defined headers so that the mail is more likely to not land in the spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a spam filter issue. Have you set up a proper Sender ID/SPF framework in your domain name service so that the host appears to be a valid MTA for this domain? Look [here](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/debian/setting-up-spf-senderid-domain-keys-and-dkim.html) for a detailed explanation of Sender ID/SPF/DKIM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spam folder.

GMail is able to differenciate if a mail has been sent from outlook for example or an automated application. (I dont know how, but they can). If i send an email from my work account to GMAil works, if its a web app or executable with the same email adress, it ends up on the spam folder.